# Read Only TextBox Value Disappears on postback

Tags: asp.net

I want to keep `TextBox` attribute `Read Only` in web form. But when I keep this `Read Only` , On `PostBack`its values get vanishes and I get empty text. How can I achieve the same functionality without loosing `TextBox` values.

Comment: Please share with us your code. Its a small detail here that lose it, maybe the viewstate is false, maybe you need to add the IsPostBack.

Comment: No, readonly textbox will send its value just fine. You probably have it **disabled** which indeed doesn't send the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by preventing user to enter values in the textbox, thus add following attributes to the textbox. It will maintain values even on postback also.

```
onkeypress="return false;"
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it by removing the ReadOnly=”true” from the tag , we will add it in the code.

Now in the code add the following :
TextBox1.Attributes.Add(“readonly”, “readonly”);

Answer (score 0):

You probably have it like this right now:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MyTextBox" runat="server" Enabled="false" />
```

Just change this to:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MyTextBox" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" />
```

And it will send its value over postback like all other form elements while still being read only.